# Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/rxjs/RX(…)

Tags: angular

I have imported `Rx` in my app, and there is no syntax error in my code:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/RX';
```

but when i run my code i face with an error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/rxjs/RX 404 (Not Found)
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/rxjs/RX(…)
```

It seems that, it cannot collect `RX` in the `GET` request.
I have checked my `node_module` folder and i have RX in the path: `rxjs/util/RX`
so i changed my import to

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/util/RX';
```

But it leads to an error. What can i do?

Comment: try  import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
import 'rxjs/Rx'
```

and check out the official angular.io I dont this you are importing correctly my friend. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#enable-rxjs-operators
and note there is a small observable import section in blue on the .io